# How to remove extra space from the top and bottom of the UITextview in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitextview

I want to remove the extra spaces between the top , bottom and in between the text.
I've tried with this one, but it's removed all the new lines.

```
let newString = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
```

Result -  **hellohow are youhow may i help you**

Actual input:

```
hello

how are you

how may i help you
```

Expected Result:

```
hello
how are you
how may i help you
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [**stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415462-trimmingcharacters) returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the String characters contained in a given character set.

We can also just remove only whitespace, newline or both.

```
  let newString = textView.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: It's working only in the simulator and device the behaviour is same as 
 this one textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ""). Any idea why it's not working in the device. Thanks

Comment: @Devan - delete the app and install again once'

Comment: Forgot to accept your Answer dude. Accepted now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

let new = yourTextView.text.trimmingCharacters(in : .whitespacesAndNewlines)